# Spring DI : session vise object creation using aop proxy for inherited class

Tags: spring, struts2

In my project i have used struts2 and spring. Spring is used just for DI. I am having all my actions created by sessions and so as model beans via spring DI. Now I want to use inheritance  for my class which will be generated through aop based proxy and it will be per session. Coding goes as below.

```
<bean id="common.EshopDefaultAction" class="com.common.actions.EshopDefaultAction"   scope="session" >
    <property name="site" ref="master.site" />
    <property name="menu" ref="master.menu" />
    <property name="indexDAO" ref="common.indexDAO" />
    <property name="categoryDAO" ref="master.categoryDAO" />
    <property name="productDAO" ref="master.productDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="common.IndexAction" parent="common.EshopDefaultAction" class="com.common.actions.IndexAction" scope="session">
    <property name="indexInfo" ref="common.indexInfo" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

both actions are having pairs of setters and getters.
I want to have site,menu, indexDAO, categoryDAO, productDAO objects created by session for all of its child like IndexAction just shown above. Right now it creates different objects for `EshopDefaultAction` and `IndexAction`.

Adding `<aop:scoped-proxy />` to `EshopDefaultAction` bean definition gives error like

```
Invalid property 'targetBeanName' of bean class [com.common.actions.IndexAction]: 
Bean property 'targetBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. 
Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Comment: I would strongly urge you to not create actions per-session, working around how S2 is designed. It may also break if the user has multiple tabs and/or windows open. Wouldn't DAOs be singletons anyway?

Comment: Does it work without `aop:scoped-proxy`?

Comment: @dave - The original idea behind creating actions per session is to save memory. My Action contains many model objects and i don't want to create those objects per request. May be it seems stupid. The idea behind keeping my DAOs session wise is for protection for multiple user access. Please guide me if i am wrong in this idea.

Comment: @Roman - yes it is working without aop:scoped-proxy but not getting the desired behaviour. Spring injects different objects for categoryDAO at the time creation of EshopDefaultAction and IndexAction.

Comment: @BhaveshKhatri You have ether incomplete or inappropriate spring configuration, what is the reason to use the spring session-scoped actions and DAOs that easily breaks your environment?

Comment: I have got desired behaviour. Above code works perfectly.The given condition is all composite beans should be declared in session scope. Thanks for your support